# mysql join unrelated tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 table:

```
create table words(id int(3) not null primary key auto_increment, name varchar(10) not  null);
insert into words values(null, 'rock');
insert into words values(null, 'rick');
insert into words values(null, 'red');
insert into words values(null, 'black');

create table letters(id int(3) not null primary key auto_increment, name char(1) not null, lang char(2) not null);
insert into letters values(null, 'A', 'en');
insert into letters values(null, 'B', 'en');
insert into letters values(null, 'C', 'es');
```

Now, to get all words that begin with 'r' I do:
    select * from words where name like 'r%';

If I want, at the same time, also get a list of all the letters with the lang = 'en', how would the query look like?
I have tried with union, but it seems you only can use it for table with the same columns.
For each row in the result list, I want to get id (from words), name (from words) AND the concatenated list of all letters that meet the criteria lang = 'en'.
I guess I need to use join, but cant really figure out how it would look like. Is there anyone can give me some help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT  w.id, w.name,
        (
        SELECT  GROUP_CONCAT(name ORDER BY name SEPARATOR ',')
        FROM    letters
        WHERE   lang = 'en'
        )
FROM    words
```

Note that this letter list will be the same for each record. Do you really need it in the dataset? You might want to consider retrieving it in a separate query and storing on the client side.